# Tradingview GetBars not working in nuxt3js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tradingview-api, nuxt3

I have function getBars call api get data but tradingview dont show chart and call api continuous

```
getBars: async (symbolInfo, resolution, periodParams, onHistoryCallback, onErrorCallback) => {
    const { from, to, firstDataRequest } = periodParams;
    let data = {}
    await axios.get(`${url}/api/TradingView/history?symbol=${symbolInfo.name}&resolution=${resolution}&from=1642723200&to=1682553600&countback=330`).then((res) => {
      data = res.data
    })
    try {
      let bars = []
      bars = data.t.map((time, index) => ({
        time: time * 1000,
        open: data.o[index],
        high: data.h[index],
        low: data.l[index],
        close: data.c[index],
        volume: data.v[index]
      }))
      if(firstDataRequest){
        history[symbolInfo.name] = bars[bars.length - 1];
      }
      console.log('bars: ', bars)
      onHistoryCallback(bars, { noData: false });
    } catch (error) {
      onErrorCallback(error);
    }
  },
```

how to fix Tradingview GetBars not working